# some cck fields of content type not displayed (corresponding elements also not showing in devtool)

Tags: 6, entities

Out of the blue it happened that a custom content type won't display some of the cck fields I constructed for the custom content type. This happens when I just visit the a full node of that content type. 
When I go see in firebug, I also notice that the HTML elements to those custom made fields are entirely missing.

- I checked the display options under admin->content
  type->customcontenttype and everything looks the way it should.
- I checked view permissions and those are also set for anonymous and
  admin roles.

Does this sound familiar to someone that cck fields cease to be displayed in full node?

Comment: What version of Drupal and CCK are you using? Are you using any additional CCK field modules? Have you checked the display and made sure they weren't marked as hidden?

Comment: Im using cck version 6x-2.9. I have all the modules that are under CCK enabled except for FileField Meta (which relies on Getid3 I don't have). yes I checked display and none weren't marked as hidden.

Comment: It's possible that you have checked "Hide if empty" in the display settings. Do those missing fields have content when you submit the form?

Comment: Yes they sure have content. I'm having the problem with nodes that already have displayed in full glory when all of a sudden only the title, body is displayed whereas normally there is an image and an "extra info" field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an advanced version of this question that's supposed to be more clear. It's [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13199/where-to-start-looking-up-if-theres-something-wrong-with-cck-field-variables)

Answer (score 1):

You say you enabled all modules under CCK which means you probably have `Content Permissions` enabled.

`Content Permissions` module gives you per-cck-field view/edit permissions (which are all off by default!). Check that you have the correct permissions set for your fields or disable the module if you don't need that granular control.

Comment: Yes I have those permissions set I checked those. Those were set before and everything was ok, and now they're still set. It happened after I was doing css on a view that used this content type. I didn't change anything about the permissions but like I said I doublechecked.

Comment: You should temporarily switch to a core theme that hasn't been modified to rule out any theme issues (css, template files, etc).

Comment: Great idea and yes my fields do show up in a core theme so it's obviously a theme issue. (a zen-based custom theme btw).

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to admin/content/node-type/my-node-type-name/display, and check that "Exclude" is enabled for "Full node".